# Radio button state not getting updated on mouseup or click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button, label

I am using a custom image for a radio button so my radio button is hidden and i am using a label for that radio button like this :-

[Click here for JS fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/Aalind/x31epgot/5/)

```js
$('body').on('mouseup', 'label.q1odiv', function() {
  if ($('input:radio[name="radio1"]').is(':checked')) {
    // My code here
    // I want to access currently checked radio button's value here
  }
});
```

```css
input[type=radio],
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
input[type=radio] + label {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: url("http://www.clker.com/cliparts/8/V/0/V/G/Z/radiobutton-unchecked-th.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  margin-bottom: 2vw;
}
input[type=radio]:checked + label {
  background-image: url("http://www.clker.com/cliparts/M/2/V/6/F/u/radiobutton-checked-sm-th.png");
}
.radio-btn {
  width: 2vw;
  height: 2vw;
}
.options-text-div {
  margin: 0 3vw;
  font-size: 2vw;
  line-height: 2.2vw;
  width: 25vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="options" id="options1">
  <input type="radio" id="q1o0" name="radio1" checked="checked">
  <label for="q1o0" class="radio-btn q1odiv">
    <div class="im-fell-dw-pica-font options-text-div ">Kicks</div>
  </label>

  <input type="radio" id="q1o1" name="radio1">
  <label for="q1o1" class="radio-btn q1odiv">
    <div class="im-fell-dw-pica-font options-text-div ">Flip Flops</div>
  </label>

  <input type="radio" id="q1o2" name="radio1">
  <label for="q1o2" class="radio-btn q1odiv">
    <div class="im-fell-dw-pica-font options-text-div ">Stilletos</div>
  </label>

  <input type="radio" id="q1o3" name="radio1">
  <label for="q1o3" class="radio-btn q1odiv">
    <div class="im-fell-dw-pica-font options-text-div ">Boots</div>
  </label>

  <input type="radio" id="q1o4" name="radio1">
  <label for="q1o4" class="radio-btn q1odiv">
    <div class="im-fell-dw-pica-font options-text-div ">Wedges</div>
  </label>
</div>
```

The problem is whenever i check a radio button, the radio button state which i checked is not updated while i am inside the function.Hence, I get the previously checked radio button as the value instead of the currently checked one.

Answer (score 1):

a) your solution is not accessible for people with keyboards

b) It should work if you listen for the change of inputs:

https://jsfiddle.net/x31epgot/6/

```
$('body').on('change', 'input', function(){
});
```

Comment: Seems like this is working. What should i do to make it accessible with keyboards ?

Comment: At first glance, this looks accessible (https://www.sitepoint.com/replacing-radio-buttons-without-replacing-radio-buttons/). Otherwise, without styling, the native radio is of course accessible. For the sake of completeness, consider http://www.coolfields.co.uk/2011/04/accessible-forms-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/ if you want to provide access to people who use screenreaders.

Answer (score 0):

```js
//By changing the specific radio you will get the id of that radio button
$('body').on('change', 'input:radio[name="radio1"]', function() {
 console.log($('input:radio[name="radio1"]:checked').attr('id')); 
  
});
```

```css
input[type=radio],
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
input[type=radio] + label {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: url("http://www.clker.com/cliparts/8/V/0/V/G/Z/radiobutton-unchecked-th.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  margin-bottom: 2vw;
}
input[type=radio]:checked + label {
  background-image: url("http://www.clker.com/cliparts/M/2/V/6/F/u/radiobutton-checked-sm-th.png");
}
.radio-btn {
  width: 2vw;
  height: 2vw;
}
.options-text-div {
  margin: 0 3vw;
  font-size: 2vw;
  line-height: 2.2vw;
  width: 25vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="options" id="options1">
  <input type="radio" id="q1o0" name="radio1" checked="checked">
  <label for="q1o0" class="radio-btn q1odiv">
    <div class="im-fell-dw-pica-font options-text-div ">Kicks</div>
  </label>

  <input type="radio" id="q1o1" name="radio1">
  <label for="q1o1" class="radio-btn q1odiv">
    <div class="im-fell-dw-pica-font options-text-div ">Flip Flops</div>
  </label>

  <input type="radio" id="q1o2" name="radio1">
  <label for="q1o2" class="radio-btn q1odiv">
    <div class="im-fell-dw-pica-font options-text-div ">Stilletos</div>
  </label>

  <input type="radio" id="q1o3" name="radio1">
  <label for="q1o3" class="radio-btn q1odiv">
    <div class="im-fell-dw-pica-font options-text-div ">Boots</div>
  </label>

  <input type="radio" id="q1o4" name="radio1">
  <label for="q1o4" class="radio-btn q1odiv">
    <div class="im-fell-dw-pica-font options-text-div ">Wedges</div>
  </label>
</div>
```